# How can I use my own .msg?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created my own .msg and can perform "rosmsg show MyMessage".
The question is how can I use it in my C++ code?

I've seen this link that is exactly the same question (http://answers.ros.org/question/31779/how-to-use-a-message-that-i-made/) however I don't really get it all. =(

Why is there a Header header in the .msg file? Is it "standard" to have in a msg?

Where Is the MyMessage.h file saved? How do I create It? I can only find the .msg file. Since I can't find it I cant Include it in the cpp file naturally.

It also states that I should add the line  in the manifest. When I do this i get an error saying:

- The manifest must not contain the following tags: depend

How can I solve this?

Many Thanks, Patrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95406/how-can-i-use-my-own-.msg?/) by [Mr Hillgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7066/mr-hillgren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1/ `manifest.xml` is now `package.xml`.
Your should look like this one:
https://github.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/blob/master/create_package_pubsub/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/package.xml

As the syntax changed the link you mention is now obsolete.

See the tutorial example here:
https://github.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/tree/master/create_package_pubsub/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)

2/ A header is used to associate a timestamp and/or a frame with your message, this is very useful but not mandatory.

3/ Once you run `cmake` in your package, a directory called `msg_gen` will be created containing the headers and required source files. You don't have to really know where this directory is located. Just include `#include <PACKAGE/MESSAGE>` where PACKAGE is you package name and MESSAGE your message filename without the extension (`mymsg.msg` becomes `mymsg`).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr Hillgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7066/mr-hillgren/) on 2013-10-29**:
Thanks for the quick response Thomas! I still have some trouble though, I explained it in the following question: http://answers.ros.org/question/95541/error-when-trying-to-use-my-own-msg/